# Why do I get an ambiguous error when calling a Constructor inside of the same class in Java?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, call, ambiguous

I can't figure out why i'm getting an ambiguous error. This is a sample code of what I have:

```
public class MyString{
    //Data:
    private char[] theString;
    //constructors:
    public MyString(){ // default constructor
    }
    public MyString(String s){ // parameterized constructor
    }
    public MyString(char[] s){ // parameterized constructor
    }
    public MyString(MyString s){ // copy constructor
    }
    //A method that calls a constructor:
    public MyString foobar(){
        return new MyString(theString);
    }
}
```

The above generates this error when foobar() is called from somewhere else:

```
./MyString.java:15: reference to MyString is ambiguous, both method MyString(char[])
in MyString and method MyString(theString) in MyString match
                return new MyString(theString);
              ^
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: As this code works, you should give us the non working code (in another website such as ideone or grepcode).

Comment: Is that the code that's not working, or is that *similar* to the code that's not working?

Comment: I find it odd that the error would quote `method MyString(theString)` as one of the ambiguous signatures when it doesn't contain a type.

Comment: Who is voting this question up when nobody can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I think it's a compiler bug, I cannot reproduce it. What version of JDK and OS are you using? Also, can you share the code from where you are calling foobar()

Comment: @Erick Hence proved, community voice is not always right ;)

Comment: Hey Colin, I like snipplr. Anyways, I've made a wierd discovery: It is compiling in Windows but NOT in Linux! In both situations, i started with a base file: http://snipplr.com/view/42171.51664/

And modified it to this: http://snipplr.com/view/42171.51667/

Comment: This is the stub that I'm using to test the class: http://snipplr.com/view/42173.51668/

As you can see, it works! I'll have to check out the version at home and make sure everything is synced...

Comment: @Erick Yes, i find it odd too. This only happened to me at home in Linux. Now here at school in windows i didn't get the error. But in both cases I started with a previous version and added what i thought to be the same code manually. 

I'm gunna keep track of my files in snipplr now :D

Comment: Zengr, see the links above. I've posted the code on snipplr. The code here was *similar*.

Comment: Ok, it's not a platform issue. My sister FTP'd it over to me and indeed i'm getting the errors as described. Here's the malbehaving class: http://snipplr.com/view/42171.51670/ Also test it with this new stub: http://snipplr.com/view/42173.51668/

Comment: Incidentally, you might find StringUtils useful in Apache commons-lang: http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Comment: @harto thanks for the link. It was my homework to create a custom string class though. Now I have my own formatting methods. :D

Comment: @trusktr: is your sister hot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error.

But this kind of error basically happens when you try to call a function and the compiler doesn't have enough type information to determine which method to call.

e.g. if you do:

```
MyString tricky=new MyString(null);
```

Then the compiler doesn't know whether null is meant to be a char[] or a String or a MyString, so you get an ambiguous error message.

The usual way to fix this is to add an explicit cast, e.g.:

```
MyString tricky=new MyString((String)null);
```

Will work....

Answer (score 0):

Aha!! I found the problem. Lines 260 and 261 of my [code](http://snipplr.com/view/42171.51672/) were accidentally switched so the compiler was looking at my return function as a method.

It would be the equivalent of changing the above sample code to this erroneous version:

```
public class MyString{
    //Data:
    private char[] theString;
    //constructors:
    public MyString(){ // default constructor
    }
    public MyString(String s){ // parameterized constructor
    }
    public MyString(char[] s){ // parameterized constructor
    }
    public MyString(MyString s){ // copy constructor
    }
    //A method that calls a constructor:
    public MyString foobar(){
    }
        return new MyString(theString); //THIS LINE WAS OUT OF PLACE! SHOULD BE IN FOOBAR!
}
```

Comment: But that should have given you a different compiler error. An illegal start of type.

Comment: Actaully, when compiling my main() program, it didn't give that error, only the ambiguous error. Then, when I tried compiling just my MyString class by its self, it indeed gave me that error. Is it supposed to give the same error no matter what i compile (AppDriver vs Class) ?